# Draw geometry on screen using BGL module

Tags: python, game-engine, opengl

I am trying to use the bgl module to draw triangles on top of the Blender interface. My understanding is that glBegin/glEnd are deprecated, and vertex array or display list or VBO should be used instead.

But I can't seems to find the relevant functions I need (glDrawArray, glBindBuffer, etc) in the bgl module. Any insights?

my `bgl.glGetString(bgl.GL_VERSION)` is 2.1 ATI-1.8.18

Comment: come to think of it, I have never seen anyone with anything other than `glBegin` etc.. I don't think this has extended to the bgl yet, *iirc* only a part of ghost has it atm.. not sure..

Comment: I was afraid of that, but thanks for the comment.  Btw, do people think questions like this are too specific for this SE?

Comment: Not at all, this is the only legible on-topic question I've seen all day. Also questions like these are bound to show up sooner or later anyways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the available OpenGL calls exposed in the bgl API are: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bgl.html

(or in https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/source/blender/python/generic/bgl.c without the gl prefix)

It has a few OpenGL 2.0 calls, but not even all I think.
It's easy to extend it to specific functions, but we are close to the point where it makes more sense to use a full OpenGL wrapper such as PyGL (and that's why the number of functions exposed is a bit stagnated).

Comment: Thanks Dalai. Good to get an answer from a dev point of view. I will wait a few more days before 'accepting' this answer.

Comment: Any info on when switching to something like pyopengl might happen ?