# How can I draw in the 3D view with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, draw-mode

I want to write a script for blender, and I wonder how can I draw something using python in the 3D view? Like lines or triangles? I mean something like debug drawing.

Comment: do you know OpenGL ? there is bgl ( blender opengl wrapper )  you can use

Comment: Start by looking and experimenting with TextEditor -> Templates -> Python -> Operator Modal Draw

Comment: related : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/912/draw-geometry-on-screen-using-bgl-module and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/draw-points-on-screen-with-bgl-python