# Create a blank new UI section?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

Is there a way to create a completely fresh new section were you can put your addon-ui-stuff on?

It should look something like this:
[image: Example Picture of a fresh Section]

Comment: Only way right now is to compile your own Blender or overlay some other UI with openGL 2D draw calls. http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/912/7777

Comment: Yea if i only could. I have absolutely no expierience with openGL and dont know how to write the tyniest bit of code :/